# unable to uninstall truffle

Tags: truffle

I am unable to uninstall truffle using this command

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
```

Current ver is 4.1.5 , I want to uninstall and reinstall v4.1.4 as code seems to be breaking while compiling and v4.1.4 may help as per the suggestions in this forum.
While running the above it says "up to date in 0.141s (sec keep changing)".

System is ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit)

Thank you

Comment: If you execute `npm ls -g --depth 0` does truffle appears in that list? Check if your users have permissions to modify npm directory `npm get prefix`.

Comment: npm ls -g --depth 0    --> gave   .nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib
`-- npm@5.8.0    and no truffle                                                                 npm get prefix     --> gave  .nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1
thank you

Comment: If truffle didn't appear in `npm ls -g` then it is not installed. Why do you believe it still is installed?

Comment: I had installed it, also its shows version and earlier when i compile  other program with truffle it was working when i do truffle version it gives Truffle v4.1.5 (core: 4.1.5)
Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)

Comment: Try running `where truffle` to determine where it is installed.

Comment: There is no command call 'where', is it something i need to install ?

Comment: Try with `whereis truffle` (my mistake `where` is a zsh command).

Comment: truffle: /usr/bin/truffle  /home/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/truffle      this what it shows

Comment: It seems you have two different installations of truffle one done with `npm install -g` that should be uninstalled because it doesn't show on `npm ls -g`. The other was installed some other way, perhaps incorrectly run `sudo npm install -g`(?) or your distributtion manager has packages for truffle. Sorry, but I cannot advice how truffle ended up at `/usr/bin`, check with your administrator or it guy.

Answer (score 1):

For other people's convenience who has similar problem:

1. Look for where the `truffle` exists:

```
$ whereis truffle
```

if you use `zsh`, try this:

```
$ where truffle
```

2. Locate to the directory, and delete it.
3. Re-install with `npm`

Answer (score 0):

try

> npm install truffle@4.1.4 -g

I think this should work even without removing the current version you have